# deploy react app on github gh-pages

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

when I'm trying to deploy react app on gh-pages it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug or compatibility issue. You should raise this as a bug with the software you are trying to use to do the deployment. Make sure to mention that you are using Windows. But first check that the software you are trying to use is compatible with Windows. If not, you may have to run Linux, e.g. using VirtualBox or Vagrant, or using another computer.

Comment: thanks for this hint, I think this problem because I am using windows, I will try to deploy my app from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I could not deploy my react app on gh-pages github because I was using windows. on Ubuntu works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (whilst not as nice as being able to run `npm run deploy` is to manually add the build folder to a git repository and then set up GitHub pages via the website in `Settings -> GitHub Pages`